# Get all products that have a custom attribute of a value

Tags: magento2, database

Ive made a new product attribute called "product_price_family" in magento2 admin panel. This is a dropdown value. I have changed the value of product_price_family of 5 products to "test" in the attribute drop down.

Is it possible to programatically get all the products that have the attribute "product_price_family" value of "test" with custom SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The long way:**

Get the Attribute ID:

```
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = {{ATTR_CODE}}
```

Then get Option ID for this attribute value:

```
SELECT eao.option_id, eaov.value 
FROM eav_attribute_option AS eao 
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS eaov ON eao.option_id = eaov.option_id 
WHERE eao.attribute_id = {{ATTR ID}} AND eaov.value = {{ATTR VALUE}}
```

Then get the products (if this is a dropdown attribute, then the values are saved in `catalog_product_entity_int` table):

```
SELECT cpe.* 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS cpei ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id 
WHERE cpei.attribute_id = {{ATTR ID}} AND cpei.value = {ATTR VALUE ID}}
```

Of course you can write it simpler, but I wanted explain how it works.

**One line query:**

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS cpei ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON cpei.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option AS eao ON ea.attribute_id = eao.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS eaov ON eao.option_id = eaov.option_id
WHERE ea.attribute_code = {{ATTR_CODE}} AND eaov.value = {{ATTRIBUTE VALUE}}
```

Comment: I ended up using the products collection for this using the attribute filter

Comment: Well, I thought you need it for direct SQL query.

Comment: This is still useful i can confirm it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used products collection with eav filter to achieve this

```
$productsCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
                    $productsCollection
                        ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_price_family',$val["eav_att_options_val_id"]);
```